# Java scanner.nextLine() в цикле for пропускает нулевую итерацию

Tags: java, scanner

Есть код

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int сount = scan.nextInt();

for (i=0; i<сount; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    name = scan.nextLine();
}
```

> Получаем: 
>  // ждет ввод с консоли 
> 3
> //Запуск цикла
>  i=0
>  i=1
> // ждет ввод с консоли 
> text
> i=2
>  // ждет ввод с консоли
>  text2

При запуске ожидает число count, получает его и проходит в цикле count итераций, ожидая при каждой итерации ввод строки.
НО! При нулевом проходе цикла когда i=0 оно не ожидает никакого ввода и сразу перепрыгивает на i=1, и тогда уже ждет ввода. Если создать новый объект Scanner scan1 непосредственно перед циклом и обращаться к нему, тогда даже при нулевой итерации цикла оно ожидает ввод строки, как и положено. Почему тогда при использовании одного и того же объекта scan для ввода числа и строк оно перескакивает нулевую итерацию в цикле?

```
// вот так работает корректно
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int сount = scan.nextInt();

Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
for (i=0; i<сount; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    name = scan1.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: понятия не имею, что такое этот сканнер, но по логике получается, что эта строка `int сount = scan.nextInt();` лишняя.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вначале, когда вы вводите `integer`  и нажимаете  `Enter`, `input.nextInt()` считывает только чило, но не  конец строки. Когда `input.nextLine()` выполняется впервые, он читает конец строки (\n) который все еще не прочитан с прошлого ввода.

Сразу после `input.nextInt()` вызовите один раз `input.nextLine()` до цикла, и проблема решится